# Escape variable with windows path

Tags: bash, shell

I've small script that connects to windows server from debian using telnet.

There is text file with ips and path on servers:

```
192.168.1.1 c:\rs_obj\data
192.168.1.2 c:\rs_obj\data
192.168.1.3 c:\new_obj\data
```

Each server has its own path for data.

here is main script

```
  while IFS=" ": read -r ip path; do
    nohup ./tl.sh $ip $path >> tl_$ip.log &
  done < srv_list.txt
```

here is tl.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(date) : $1 $2
expect -f-<<EOF
  set timeout 20
  spawn telnet $1

  expect "login: "
  send "...\r"
  expect "password: "
  send "...\r"
  expect "*="
  send 'cd "$2"\r'
  expect "data>"
....
  send "exit\r"
EOF
exit
```

The problem is with windows path - how to pass correct string in line `send "cd $2\r"` (escape backslash and \r \n and so on)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some solution:

```
send "cd $(printf '%q' $2)\r"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there's a good way to do this really. two options I can think of. you could screw around with the quoting until it's right. But that is messy and would lose a lot of code readability.

My way round would be to manually escape the string e.g.

```
path=${2// /\\ } # substitutes all instances of ' ' with '\ ' in path
path=${path//\\/\\\\/} # substitutes all instances of '\' with '\\' in path
```

more details of manipulating strings in variables can be found [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) Hope this helps